# Expand/Collapse Grouped Cells Macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, toggle

I'm having a lot of issues with my code.

I have grouped rows (153:227) and I want to have a toggle to expand and collapse them.

This works if I do the EntireRow.Hidden function however, that unhides all the hidden cells that are within the grouping (which I would like to remain hidden).

The .ShowDetail function seems to work half the time and it will not toggle as it gives back an error if you try to "Show Detail" when the detail is already showing (if that makes sense). As such I can only expand or collapse, but I cannot do both with a toggle.

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you could kindly post your code using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63541368/edit) button below your post and explain what `grouping rows` means and how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your toggle button and assign it this code to hide/show rows (make sure that the "object box" in the VBA Editor contains the name of the toggle, and that the "procedure box" is "Click"):

```
Private Sub My_Toggle_Button()

If Range("A153", "A227").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    Me.MyToggleButton.Caption = "Hide rows"
    Me.MyToggleButton.Value = False
    Range("A153", "A227").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Me.MyToggleButton.Caption = "Show rows"
    Me.MyToggleButton.Value = True
    Range("A153", "A227").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```